# Can you help me with countup in js?

Tags: javascript, date, timer

I have this script, but I would like to subtract years from days so that the days can have a maximum of 365 days.

So I want to have 1 year 277 days .... (if today is 8.2.2021)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("May 8, 2019 15:00:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};

function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
    countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
    timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
    secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  years = Math.floor(days / 365);
  if (years > 1) {
    days = days - (years * 365)
  }
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('years')[0].innerHTML = years;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function() {
    countUpFromTime(countFrom, id);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <span class="timeel years">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefYears">years</span>
  <span class="timeel days">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefDays">days</span>
  <span class="timeel hours">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefHours">hours</span>
  <span class="timeel minutes">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefMinutes">minutes</span>
  <span class="timeel seconds">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefSeconds">seconds</span>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: It will not go inside your condition maybe `>= 1` solves your problem

Comment: Yeah, thats it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it will not go inside the condition, just update it to `>=1`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("May 8, 2019 15:00:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};

function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
    countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
    timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
    secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  years = Math.floor(days / 365);
  if (years >= 1) {
    days = days - (years * 365)
  }
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('years')[0].innerHTML = years;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function() {
    countUpFromTime(countFrom, id);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <span class="timeel years">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefYears">years</span>
  <span class="timeel days">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefDays">days</span>
  <span class="timeel hours">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefHours">hours</span>
  <span class="timeel minutes">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefMinutes">minutes</span>
  <span class="timeel seconds">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefSeconds">seconds</span>
</div>
```